# Display ads on top of canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, admob

Right now I'm calling my gamecanvas like so:

```
GameCanvas gameCanvas;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gameCanvas = new GameCanvas(getApplicationContext());
    gameCanvas.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    setContentView(gameCanvas);
}
```

In my main.xml i got

```
`<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-ID"
                                       ads:adSize="BANNER"/>`
```

If i set the contentView to my main.xml i can get an add showing as so

```
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("DEVICE ID").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

So how can i add an admob banner ad on top of the canvas?

EDIT:

If i add

```
<mb.jet.game.GameCanvas android:id="@+id/vMain"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to my xml I get the error

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mb.jet.game/mb.jet.game.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class mb.jet.game.GameCanvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making everything into a relative layout so that my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/vMain"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                                           ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2945740687682775/6253169713"
                                           ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

after that i added the canvas view to the relative layout and the ad afterwards like so

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.vMain);
    layout.addView(gameCanvas);
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("91BA1C88FB7946232E39E67D0C066208").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution or if it's what someone else posted and i just misunderstood, so i'll leave the question open for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. Put your gamecanvas into a fragment. Dynamically add your fragment to your activity via a FrameLayout. Put the FrameLayout in a RelativeLayout. Put the Admob xml stuff in the relativelayout too. It all becomes simple then, since you can position your gamecanvas relative to your ads. I am ASSUMING that your gamecanvas is a GLSurfaceView (probably wrong)? Whatever the case, you can create the view using xml.

Once all that is done then add the following attribute to your admob xml reference ...

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

add to your framelayout

```
android:layout_above ="@+id/adView"
```

You can also add a view to your layout using addContentView, but if you ask me it is better to use Fragments. =)

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how would i go about putting my gamecanvas into a fragment? Just extend Fragment instead of View? and my gamecanvas is just a normal canvas :)

Comment: extend fragment, in oncreateview return the actual view that you will be using. in your activity use setcontentview to set a framelayout to your activity, since fragments can be easily dynamically added to framelayouts. once you do that you got the ball rolling. Plz upvote if this has helped you... THANKS

Comment: If i extend fragment instead of view in my gamecanvas class a lot of things break such as getWidth or getContext and i really quite need those, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: @Nujke, You can do everything programmatically without using XML. If you don't want it that way, define a framelayout, place the canvas first then the adview last. Thanks

Comment: if you extend Fragment... instead of using getContext you can use getActivity(), which returns the context. I don't know enough about canvas, but if canvas is anything like a surfaceview or glsurfaceview then there should be some methods that you can override to get the height and width of the surface so that you can obtain the correct aspect ratio. I know that if you dynamically add it to your layout using fragments, getting the height and width shouldn't be a problem since fragments work closely with your activity.